# Get the Row the user Right Clicked on in a Grid before they click on an item in the Context Menu

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, devexpress, gridcontrol

I've got a DevExpress `GridControl`, which has a `ContextMenuStrip` with 2 Items on it.
I want to be able right click a record in the `GridControl` and launch the user's default browser and search for a term using their default search engine with one of the items in the `ContextMenu`.

My code:

```
    int rowX, rowY;

    private void genericView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            rowX = MousePosition.X;
            rowY = MousePosition.Y;
        }
    }

    private void tsmSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int key = GetRowAt(gdcErrorLogDefaultView, rowX, rowY);

        if (key < 0)
            return;

        string ex = gdcErrorLogDefaultView.GetRowCellValue(key, "Exception").ToString();
        //Logic to launch browser & search for ex
    }

    public int GetRowAt(GridView view, int x, int y)
    {
        return view.CalcHitInfo(new Point(x, y)).RowHandle;
    }
```

I know GetRowAt calculates the row properly, I use it for a number of other purposes elsewhere in my code. However, it is not properly getting a key in my tsmSearch_Click event.

While testing, I set a breakpoint on my `if` statement in the Click event. `key` = -2147483648. I expect 0 because in this particular test there's only 1 row in my grid.

Is there a different way to achieve this? The grid supports multiselect, so I don't want to "overwrite" their selection by programmatically selecting the row as soon as they right click.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to describe:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And of course as soon as I finally decide to post this question, I realized my problem. The MouseDown event should be as follows:

```
private void genericView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        rowX = e.X;
        rowY = e.Y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> I expect 0 because in this particular test there's only 1 row in my grid

It is incorrect to expect `0` in this case. Moreover the `-2147483648` is a valid value for Row Handle (this value representing the invalid row handle).
Please refer to the [Identifying Rows and Cards](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument642) help-article for more information regarding row handles.

I believe in your case it is better to obtain the handles of selected rows by the [ColumnView.GetSelectedRows](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetSelectedRowstopic) method. Refer to the [Selections Overview](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument711) document for more information.

Related examples:

1. [How to: Identify the Grid's Element Located Under the Mouse Cursor](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3052)
2. [How to: Obtain and Modify Selected Rows](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11863)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but Right Clicking doesn't Select a row so it's possible the user would have no selection. Thus I need to get the row at the mouse location. And since the row indices are 0 based, why is it wrong to expect 0? 0 is the first entry, and there's only 1 row. What else could it possibly be?

Comment: @sab669 row handles are not zero-based - for example row indices of any group-row is negative, row index of new-item row is -2147483647 (see the help article in my links). Anyway this is not a problem in your case but it can be a problem in general. As it specified in Mouse Cursor example you should use the client-based coordinates for hit-testing, e.g. `e.Location` instead of `Control.MousePosition` which is screen-based.

Comment: Of course they are zero based. And GetSelectedRows is not updated until after the Mouse Down events fires - too late in this case.

Comment: @Grantly There is nothing wrong in my answer, so it is not quite clear to me why you down-voting. **Data row** handles are zero-based only, but, in general,  there are group-rows, filter-rows, detail-rows which handles are not zero-based. Moreover any sorting or filtering operations can change a zero-based order of data-rows.

Comment: @DmitryG Your answer is very informative, but it does miss the point and lacks focus on the question.  Zero based 'generally' is understood as the First element is indexed by a Zero.  This is how RowHandles work, despite also having more -ve values.  So this first point you obfuscated rather than assisted.  The OP is correct to assume IF the first row is focused, that the Handle will be a zero in his example.